# Tox can't copy non-python file while installing the module

Tags: python, setuptools, tox

This is the tree structure of the module I'm writing the `setup.py` file for:

```
ls .

LICENSE
README.md
bin
examples
module
scratch
setup.py
tests
tox.ini
```

I configured my `setup.py` as follows:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="package_name",
    version="0.1",
    packages=find_packages(),

    install_requires=[
        # [...]
    ],

    extras_require={
        # [...]

    },

    tests_require={
        'pytest',
        'doctest'
    },

    scripts=['bin/bootstrap'],

     data_files=[
        ('license', ['LICENSE']),
     ],

    # [...]
    # could also include long_description, download_url, classifiers, etc.
)
```

If I install the package from my python environment (also a virtualenv)

```
pip install .
```

the `LICENSE` file gets correctly installed.

But running `tox`:

```
[tox]
envlist = py27, py35

[testenv]
deps = 
    pytest
    git+https://github.com/djc/couchdb-python
    docopt

commands = py.test \
    {posargs}
```

I get this error:

```
running install_data
  creating build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/wheel/leafline-0.1.data
  creating build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/wheel/leafline-0.1.data/data
  creating build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/wheel/leafline-0.1.data/data/license
  error: can't copy 'LICENSE': doesn't exist or not a regular file
```

Removing the `data_files` part from the setup.py makes `tox` running correctly.

Comment: Could you try to run `python setup.py install` and see what will happen? As far as I remember `pip install .` works the same as `python setup.py develop` and tox uses `install` command.

Comment: What operating system is this run on (for the bounty)?

Answer (score 9):

Your issue here is that setuptools is not able to find the 'LICENSE' file in the files that have been included for building the source distribution. You have 2 options, to tell setuptools to include that file (both have been pointed to here):

- Add a `MANIFEST.in` file (like https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/)
- Use `include_package_data=True` in your setup.py file.

Using `MANIFEST.in` is often simpler and easier to verify due to https://pypi.org/project/check-manifest/, making it possible to use automation to verify that things are indeed correct (if you use a VCS like Git or SVN).

---

`pip install .` builds a wheel using `python setup.py bdist_wheel` which is installed by simply unpacking it appropriately, as defined in the Wheel Specification: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/

`tox` builds a source distribution using `python setup.py sdist`, which is then unpacked and installed using `python setup.py install`.

That might be a reason for the difference in behavior for you.

Comment: Bounty awarded. Nice complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have some resource files inside my packages which I use during the execution. To make setup store them in a package with python code, I use `include_package_data=True` and I access them using `importlib.resources`. You can use backport for an older Python version than 3.7 or another library.

Before each release I have a script which verifies, that all files I need are placed inside a `bdist` wheel to be sure that everything is on the place.